# Let $V$ be a vector space. Let $S$ and $T$ be subsets (not necessarily subspaces) of $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is it necessarily true that:

(a) Span$(S+T)$ $\subseteq$ Span$(S)$ + Span$(T)$

(b) Span$(S+T)$ $\supseteq$ Span$(S)$ + Span$(T)$

The question also hints to use theorem 4.13 which states:

'Let $V$ be a vector space. Let $S$ be a subset of $V$ . Then Span$(S)$ is the intersection of all subspaces $U$ of $V$ such that $S \subseteq U$.'

Despite the hint/clue however, I still don't know how to even begin to tackle this question. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And I suppose $S+T=\{s+t\mid s\in S,t\in T\}$? (It's standard for subspaces, but less so for subsets, hence my question.)

Comment: (a) is obvious from the definition of span. For (b) take a really simple case. Suppose $S=\{v\}$ and $T=\{-v\}$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Indeed

Comment: The first part has also be asked about here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2659505/the-span-of-the-sum-of-subsets-is-a-subset-of-the-sum-of-spans?rq=1, and the same question has been asked last week : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2652737/spanu-w-%E2%8A%86-spanu-spanw?rq=1 (it's closed at the moment but it might be reopened soon).