# Span(S + T) ⊇ Span(S) + Span(T)

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm given the following problem to solve but I can't figure out the solution

---

Let V be a vector space. Let S and T be subsets (not necessarily subspaces) of V.

(a) Is it necessarily true that Span(S + T) ⊆ Span(S) + Span(T)? Justify your answer.

(b) Is it necessarily true that Span(S + T) ⊇ Span(S) + Span(T)? Justify your answer.

---

To solve part (a) I've taken the definition of span and shown that the lhs is just a particular case of the rhs, i.e. when all the coefficients of *$s_i$* are equal to all the coefficients of *$t_i$*

---

Any suggestion for how to go for part (b)?

Comment: Well, how is your intuition? Do you think this should be true? False?

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2659992/let-v-be-a-vector-space-let-s-and-t-be-subsets-not-necessarily-subspaces?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: My guts tell me that (a) is true and (b) is false.

Comment: By the way, is the way I've proved (a) acceptable?

Comment: Yeah. You got the idea on a). In the end you have to still write it down in a proper way - if you're new to this, that might be the harder part. If you want a simple solution look at the link provided above by Arnauld. The question comments there contain one. It's pretty simple. And your guts are telling you right.

Comment: Thanks for the input, and I'm new to proving these sort of theorems, the main problem now is that even though I've read the link and researched a while I still have no idea how to go for part (b), like where to start from

Answer (score 1):

Part a. Use

- $S\subseteq\operatorname{Span}(S)$;
- if $S\subseteq S'$ and $T\subseteq T'$ then $S+T\subseteq S'+T'$
- if $S\subseteq U$, with $U$ a subspace, then $\operatorname{Span}(S)\subseteq U$.

Part b. Consider $S=\{x\}$ and $T=\{-x\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $S=\{(1,0)\}$ and $T=\{(0,1)\}$ and compute LHS and RHS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think part b is true. For a counterexample take $S = \{v\}$ and $T = \{−v\}$.